# IP tunnel over Linux serial default shell

Tags: linux, serial-port, ip, tunnel

This is a more constrained version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890505/socat-tunnel-ip-through-tty) question:

I have an embedded ARM device running a custom image with a Linux 3.10.0 kernel.

The only physical interface (no, USB, no Ethernet) is the default Linux shell which is connected one of the serial interfaces.

My question is: Is there any built-in or external tool that opens an IP tunnel over this connection?

I see some general issues:

- The device is already use by Linux, so it must use stdin/out to communicate instead of accessing the device directly.
- After starting the tunneling application, the application must wait for a tunnel client to connect because I need to close the serial connection on my computer and then start the tunnel client.
- There should be a way to close the connection and go back to the normal shell

The actual requirement is, that I can access a REST interface that is running on the embedded device from a computer connected to the embedded device via serial cable.

This already works on devices with a physical Ethernet or Ethernet-over-USB but this device does not offer that.

**[UPDATE]**
As explained, socat is currently not available on our embedded device so as a first attempt, I used the following:

- A Linux (Ubuntu) laptop with a physical serial interface
- A Windows Laptop with a physical serial interface and cygwin+socat installed
- Both connected via Null-modem cable

*Note:* I'm using a Windows laptop on one side because we will have the socat client running on Linux (unfortunately).

1. Direct STDIO Connection

**Server**

```
socat stdio file:/dev/ttyS0,b115200
```

**Client**

```
socat file:/dev/ttyS4,b115200 stdio
```

In cygwin, `ttyS0` is `COM1`, `ttyS4` in this case is `COM5`.

Using these, socat works like a little chat program. Why I type on one side is output on the other and vice-versa.

2. TCP Connection

The next step is to use a TCP connection.

**Server**

```
socat /dev/ttyS0,b115200,crtscts=1,raw,echo=0 tcp-connect:localhost:80
```

**Client**

```
socat -T2 file:/dev/ttyS4,b115200,crtscts=1,raw,echo=0 tcp-l:7777,reuseaddr
```

I specified the baud rate (115200), used raw transmission, no echo (The HTTP request would otherwise be sent back to the requester) using hardware flow control. Pus I had to use a timeout `-T2` wich terminates the connection after 2s. Otherwise, curl does not terminate either and waits for more data.

When I use curl on the windows computer, it successfully transmits the request over serial connection and returns the complete HTTP response of the HTTP server on the Linux computer:

```
curl localhost:7777/index.html
```

However, it works only once. After the request is completed, both `socat`client and server terminates.

Moreover, when I use a browser (Chorme), it uses g-zip encoding which most probably sends binary characters. And one of these characters will be a `EOF` character which again terminates `socat` before completing the request/response.

Then I tried to add `fork` to the server:

```
socat /dev/ttyS0,b115200,crtscts=1,raw,echo=0 tcp-connect:localhost:80,fork
```

This keeps the server alive, but `curl` returns a `400 Bad Request`. So it seems as if the `socat` server initiated a request for each line or chunk since it does not understand HTTP.

3. IP Connection

Then I thought about going a layer below and using a TUN connection. However, this is not implemented on the Windows version of `socat`.

4. HTTP connection

Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I understand, `socat`does not provide a connection type that actually understands HTTP and is able to serialize it properly over a serial connection.

So, I couldn't find any stable way to start both client and server and run multiple HTTP requests over the serial connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a normal linux, you could use `socat`.

This program allows you to connect several stream types (file, socket, tcp, udp, ...). In your case it would be tcp to file or more precisely a tcp socket at port xx to /dev/ttyUSB1. You should launch socat on both sides to build a tunnel.

**Edit 1:**
Sorry I got also disappointed by socat. I can't find a solution that keeps my TCP listener active for multiple successive connections, but handles only one connection at a time.

My solution is a simple C# program that uses 4 threads:
 1. wait for input on stdin e.g. exit command
 2. the TCP listener
 3. the TCP worker thread for a active connection
 4. if TCP is open, it opens another thread for COM

Thread 3 reads from TCP and writes to COM and Tread 4 reads from COM and writes to TCP. If thread gets a TCP close event, it stops thread 4, which closes COMx, and exits it self. Now thread 2 can accept a new connection. If thread 1 reads exit on stdin, it passes a message to all threads to stop and shutdown.

Maybe you can implement such a short program in C with pthreads on your embedded system, which has no socat.

The EOF problem:
I tried to google for a program that escapes a special character or reencodes a data stream from ASCII to ANSI or base64 or whatever.... If you can find such a program or write it also in C you can pipe it in between

```
Server <=> reencode <=> socat <--serial--> socat <=> reencode <=> client
```

Comment: As explained, I cannot directly use a device since there is no pyhsical USB available and the only physical serial device is used by the kernel. However, from what the man page says, I think in my case I need to use STDIN / STDOUT on the embedded side and and a serial device on the other side. Is socat waiting until a client connects and how to I close the socat connection?

Comment: Yes it's waiting. You can also define a Character that is handled as EOF or TCP.close(). I'm using socat the other way around: tunneling serial over TCP.

Comment: Unfortunately, socat is not available on our target system and it is not included in our BSP/build system. That means, I cannot tests it without adding a custom package and rebuilding the Linux image. However, from what the man page says, it does exactly what I need so I accept this answer. As soon as I have tested it, I will post and update.

Comment: I would appreciate if you may have a look on my updated posting. Do you see any way to get around any of the problems mentioned?

Comment: Thanks for your update. Yes, although socat is very powerful and versatile, it seems as if there a few special cases that won't work. Before evaluating socat, I was actually thinking about writing such a tool by myself. But I was skeptic about reinventing the wheel. I think using the serial line requires some basic transport protocol that escapes control characters, uses some error correction/detection and allows flow control on a higher level to signalize that a connection is closed e.g.

Comment: My use case is an FPGA board with an UART @ 1MBit/s. I wanted to access my board from home, through university firewall and through my workstation. So I tunnel UART over TCP. One problem is the connection reuseability, because I wanted socat to stay alive if I disconnect and reconnect on the TCP side. And I wanted socat to limit connections to 1, so there are no race conditions if multiple clients write to UART.

Answer (score 0):

We've now solved the problem halfway using [pppd](https://ppp.samba.org/pppd.html). As it turns out, even Windows supports [ppp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol). In contrast to `socat`, `pppd` actually uses a protocol that will have error detection included and it automatically creates network devices on the Linux and Windows system.

The only problem is, that `pppd` requires to have access to the serial device. There is no direct mode like the `ppp` tool provides.

We are now disabling the shell on demand, rebooting into IP-over-serial mode. When we are done, we reboot the system which automatically switch back to `getty` using the serial line.

The is not the prettiest solution but right now, it seems to work.